# Error on Install PHPUnit Through Pear

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

Installing PHPUnit via PEAR the install instructions for phpunit are running this:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

But fails with this error:

> Notice: fwrite(): send of 105 bytes failed with errno=10053 An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine.  in PEAR\Downloader.php on line 1664
>
> Notice: fwrite(): send of 105 bytes failed with errno=10053
>   An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine.
>   in C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR\Downloader.php on line 1664
>
> Discovering channel pear.phpunit.de over http:// failed with message:
>
> channel-add: Cannot open "http://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml"
>   (File http://pear.phpunit.de:80/channel.xml not valid
>   (redirected but no location))
>
> Trying to discover channel pear.phpunit.de over https://
>   instead
>
> Discovery of channel "pear.phpunit.de" failed
>   (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml"
>   (Connection to `pear.phpunit.de:443' failed:
>
> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.))

How do you solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you set the auto discover on?  I do the following at it works correctly on Ubuntu Linux and Windows 7.

Ubuntu:

```
sudo pear upgrade PEAR
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Windows:

```
pear upgrade PEAR
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Comment: The setting has nothing to do with it - he explicitely calls `channel-discover`.

Comment: Tanks. problem was in connection internet

Comment: I saw that, but there are other channels that are needed to complete the install of PHPUnit.  Without these, it will fail as well.  I believe you need the components.ez.no and pear.symfony.com channels as well.